# GET request from eclipse IDE not working as expected

Tags: jquery, ajax, eclipse, spring-mvc

I'm sending a few AJAX requests under a click event using this script:

```
$(function() {
    $(document).on('click', ".playImage", function() {
        clearPlayList();
        addPath($(this).parent().attr('id'));
        play()

    });
});

function clearPlayList() {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var uri = encodeURI("http://localhost:8080/WebMediaPlayer/PlayList");
        $.ajax({
            url: uri,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'DELETE',
            async: false,
        });
    });
}

function addPath(path) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var uri = encodeURI("http://localhost:8080/WebMediaPlayer/PlayList");
        $.ajax({
            url: uri,
            async: false,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            type: 'POST',
            data: path,
        })
    });
}

function play() {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var uri = encodeURI("http://localhost:8080/WebMediaPlayer/PlayList");
        $.ajax({
            url: uri,
            async: false,
        });
    });
}
```

This is my controller:

```
@RestController
public class PlayListController {
    @RequestMapping(method= RequestMethod.GET,path = "/WebMediaPlayer/PlayList")
    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.OK)
    public void get(@RequestParam(value="path", defaultValue="") String path) {
        MediaPlayerController player =new  MediaPlayerController();
        player.play();
    }

    @RequestMapping(method= RequestMethod.POST,path = "/WebMediaPlayer/PlayList")
    public void post(HttpServletRequest request, @RequestBody String mediaPath) {
        MediaPlayerController player =new  MediaPlayerController();
        player.add(mediaPath);
    }


    @RequestMapping(method= RequestMethod.DELETE,path = "/WebMediaPlayer/PlayList")
    public void delete() {
        MediaPlayerController player =new  MediaPlayerController();
        player.stop();
    }
}
```

Whenever I click the play button the POST and DELETE requests are sent fine and I
hit the server method. The problem is the GET request is not being sent.

When I restart Eclipse and click the button for the first time after restarting the GET is sent fine. I tried to send the GET request via a Google REST client and it seems to be working well.

Any idea what can cause this behavior?

Comment: 1) remove `async: false`. It's really, *really* bad practice. If you check the console you'll see warnings about using it. 2) Remove the `document.ready` handlers from within your functions

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding type : GET to the AJAX Request?

Comment: yes I tried, although I think it's the default type